# how to show record in popup using php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to show the record in the popup using PHP and MySQL. it is showing only the last record in the popup I want to show the selected record

```
    $s = mysql_query("Select * from student");

        while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($s))
        {
        echo'<div class="ammad">'. $sql["id"]."".$sql["Name"]."".$sql["Subject"].'</div>';
        echo '<input ammad="'.$sql["id"].'" type="submit" class="abc" id="abc"/>';

            $name=$sql["id"];

        }

                echo '  
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <input type="textbox" value="'.$name.'" />
</div>';
```

the dialog is my popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


$(".abc").click(function(){
$( "#dialog" ).dialog().close();    

    var b = $(this).attr("ammad");
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();    
    });
});

</script>
```

It is showing only the last record in popup I want to show the selected record in the popup

Comment: you shouldn't have same `id="abc"` for each input..

Comment: `$name` is only the last record because it is outside the loop. It doesn't look like you are using `b` anywhere..

Comment: how to place it properly ??

Answer (score 0):

Just you doesn't update the diaglog box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){


$(".abc").click(function(){
$( "#dialog" ).dialog().close();    

    var b = $(this).attr("ammad");

    $("#dialog").html('<input type="textbox" value="' +b+ '/>');

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();    
    });
});

</script>
```

Try like this and remove { id="abc" } inside loop because id selectors must be unique.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp